# Groovy/Java map sort

Tags: java, dictionary, groovy, hashmap

I have percentage values in map with flags, like-
[44.4: true, 0.0: false, 44.4: false, 38.9: false, 0.0 false]

I want to sort them in descending order. The code that I'm using loses the duplicate keys. I do not want to lose them since I want to display all values in the output.

```
def secDisc = [:]
def discount = plan."${section}"
if(plan."${section}"!=null && plan.bluePlan)
secDisc."$discount" = true
else if(plan."${section}"!=null && !plan.bluePlan)
secDisc."$discount" = false
secDisc = secDisc.sort {a, b -> b.key <=> a.key}
secDisc.each{disc, flag->

        println "disc- $disc flag- $flag"
 }
```

When I print it, only one 0.0 value is left. 
Thanks!

Comment: It is strange that you were able to put duplicate values in a map in the first place (if the backing store is really a `Map`) -- or you may want to use an `IdentityHashMap`? Not sure how you do that in Groovy though.

Comment: You probably want to rethink using decimals as your Map keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rethink the kind of data structure you are using.  You have the value of the map being a boolean, but you are trying to put multiple identical keys into the map.  This will not work.

Instead, I'd try making the values a list of booleans, so your example becomes:

```
 [44.4: [true, false], 0.0: [false, false], 38.9: [false]]
```

This will ensure that duplicate keys are never lost.  Also, sorting will be simpler.  Also, as @tim_yates mentioned, I'd convert your keys to strings with a fixed number of decimals to ensure that floating point math doesn't produce values that are slightly off in the 12th decimal digit.

You haven't mentioned if sorting is important for identical keys with different values.

Comment: Thanks. I can't make keys strings because I'm sorting them in descending order after populating the map in this step- secDisc = secDisc.sort {a, b -> b.key <=> a.key}. Ordering of identical keys with different values does not matter.

Comment: I'd still be careful about floating point math differences.  If you can't do strings, but you do know how many significant digits there are, I would consider multiplying by 10^2 (or however many decimal digits you care about) and use integers instead.